# curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 3

Tags: json, curl, post, solr

Im trying to index a simple json data in solr using curl. When i use the command, it says

```
"curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json'-d http://localhost:8983/solr/informationretrieval/update/json/docs '[{"id":"1","title":"Doc 1"},{"id":"2","title":"Doc 2"}]'
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":1}}
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 3"
```

I have tried removing quotes, tried -g and --globoff etc but every time there are errors like illegal port number. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You're missing a `-d` or `--data` before the string you want to POST. (and remove the `-X POST`)

Answer (score 0):

Adding Multiple JSON Documents

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/informationretrieval/update' --data-binary '
    [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Doc 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Doc 2"
      }
    ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

you just placed the **-d** in the wrong position. It should be after the URL but immediately before the data being sent.
*curl --help post*